# Find the derivative of the complex function $f(z)=f(x+iy)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Can someone please check my math?
Forgive the nonstandard notation

$$f(z)=f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=f_x(x,y)+i f_y(x,y)$$

From a website I got

$${df \over dz} = {\partial f_x \over \partial x} + i {\partial f_y \over \partial x} = -i{\partial f_x \over \partial y} + {\partial f_y \over \partial y}$$

Cauchy–Riemann conditions are

$$\frac{\partial f_x}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f_y}{\partial y}\ ,\ \frac{\partial f_x}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial f_y}{\partial x}$$

Therefore

$${df \over dz} = {\partial f_x \over \partial x} - i {\partial f_x \over \partial y} = i{\partial f_y \over \partial x} + {\partial f_y \over \partial y}$$

So the derivative of a complex function f is a complex number whose real part gives the rate of change of $f_x$ in one direction and the imaginary part gives the rate of change of $f_x$ in the direction perpendicular to the first.

The rate of change of $f_y$ is the same as $f_x$ but with the real and imaginary parts reversed and there is a change of sign too.

Comment: The notation $f_x$ is usually replaced with $u$ and $f_y$ with $v$ then $\frac{df}{dz} = u_x+iv_x$ where $u_x$ and $v_x$ denote partial derivatives with respect to $x$. Notice, you can also just keep partial derivatives with respect to $x$ or $y$ by appropriate use of the Cauchy Riemann equations.